# Wazuh Docker installation

Tags: wazuh

Hi I have installed Wazuh on my local docker environment as mention below https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/deployment-options/docker/docker-installation.html
But now i need to change the local host IP address from 127.0.0.1 that access the Wazuh manager. any idea how to do it?
Please help

I tried to look ad wzauh manager with vi command but cant seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Although StackOverflow asks the answers not to ask for clarification, I must ask you to clarify what you want to do concretely since your question is ambiguous in the context in which you are asking it as I will explain below, anyway, I will try to answer you these three questions I raise below about your case

- Do you want to change the IP of the container through which the other containers communicate with it? For example the Wazuh dashboard container for the connection with the Wazuh app?
- Do you want to modify any value of the Wazuh manager configuration (ossec.conf)? Per example: **<white_list>127.0.0.1</white_list>**
- Do you want to modify the IP of the Wazuh dashboard user interface (WUI)?

About the value specified in the **ossec.conf** file, this is specifically related to Active Response:

- https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/reference/ossec-conf/global.html#white-list

> This specifies an IPv4 address, netblock, or hostname for which Active
> Responses will not be triggered. Only one of those values may be
> specified for each <while_list> tag, but several values may be used by
> including multiple <white_list> tags. This configuration is compared
> against the extracted srcip field in the alert.

```
  <global>
    <white_list>127.0.0.1</white_list>
    <white_list>^localhost.localdomain$</white_list>
  </global>
```

Note that the communication between containers is done through the internal network that Docker internally creates and the connection between containers is done by referring to the name of the service, for example, in the single-node docker-compose.yml file there are 3 services: **wazuh.manager**, **wazuh.indexer**, and **wazuh.dashboard**, the port configuration between them is also specified in this file (Wazuh dashboard is configured in port 5601 inside the container but from the host, this port is redirected through 443, so the Wazuh dashboard interface is accessed through **https://0.0.0.0**).

An example would be the one used in the Wazuh dashboard container, in the  **/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/data/wazuh/config/wazuh.yml** file, where reference is made to '**url: "https://wazuh.manager"**'

About the ports, a deployment performed on my local machine looks like this, is in this output where you are seeing **127.0.0.1**?

```
╰─➤  sudo netstat -tuplen | grep -E "1514|1515|55000|514|9200|443"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1515            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          205714     20725/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1514            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          221209     20743/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          224335     21284/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9200            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          215526     20660/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          210906     20706/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::1515                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          211841     20731/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::1514                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          211846     20749/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          225318     21296/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::9200                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          210859     20668/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::55000                :::*                    LISTEN      0          215547     20713/docker-proxy
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*                           0          221229     20761/docker-proxy
udp6       0      0 :::514                  :::*                                0          211851     20768/docker-proxy
```

Regarding the vi editor, note that there is no persistence in the containers as it is not the philosophy of Docker containers, any changes should be done by external persistence, in any case, you can perform recursive searches using the **grep -R "value"** command.